# How to update development environment when working with SendGrid Web api using Php

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid-api-v3

[image]

i am following :
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

there is no detail regarding how to get the environment variable from the shell to the php environment.

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Actually the following text in Sendgrid page is confusing:
"Update the development environment (user space) with your SENDGRID_API_KEY".

Basically what it means is to add a new environment variable.
Windows users can open environment variable through control panel/system/advanced system settings.
[Windows10 UI for adding Environment variable][1]

And then in the code you write like this:

```
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
```

PS. Please restart your VisualStudio to see the newly added environment variable!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTo77.png

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio was an important step :) Thanks

Comment: me i restarted the server instead because it was giving me a null for the apiKey

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid offers customers the ability to manage the security of their accounts and their sending with API keys.

Link: https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys

API Keys allow you to generate an authentication credential that is separate from your username and password. They are independent from one another and are easily disposable. You should create unique API keys for each of your applications or servers so that you can easily revoke them without disrupting other systems if needed.

Example:

```
Authorization: Bearer 
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
```

Reference Link:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShOQxpX7Dcw